# Exiftool - modify metadata format

Tags: exiftool

Suppose I have 5000 images with following metadata in the LABEL field.

```
0001 ELEPHANT
0002 ELEPHANT
0003 ELEPHANT
...
4999 ELEPHANT
5000 ELEPHANT
```

I wish to change the format to:

```
ELEPHANT-0001
ELEPHANT-0002
ELEPHANT-0003
…
ELEPHANT-4999
ELEPHANT-5000
```

In other words, I want to do the following for a metadata field of multiple images:

#### NAME     —>     NAME-####

From what I can gather there could be two ways of doing this

1. Ignore the current metadata in the images, and reference a (plain text? csv?) file that I prepare separately; or
2. Read the file's metadata as a string, identify the space and the number preceding the space, save that number, and finally make a new string by concatenating the number and space, and adding a hyphen in between!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon the answer I gave in the [exiftool forums](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,8338.msg42797.html).

The basic command would be
`exiftool "-LABEL<${LABEL;s/(\d{4}) (.*)/$2-$1/}" <FileOrDir>`

You basically want to copy a tag into the same tag, with some modifications.  The option to copy a tag is the less than (or greater than) symbol `<` or `>`.  A common mistake is to use the equal sign `=` which is used to assign a static value to a tag.

To do the modification to the tag, it takes the Advance Formatting option, which is actually some in-line perl code.  In this example, the tag is treated as a perl string and a regex substitution is used.  It matches and captures the first four digits `(\d{4})`, matches the space (but doesn't capture it), then matches and captures the rest of the tag `(.*)`.  The two captures are assigned to the variables `$1` and `$2`, respectively.  In the replace half of the substitution `$2-$1`, the two captures are reversed with the hyphen between them.

To take full advantage of the advance formatting, some basic perl and regex knowledge is helpful.

Once you are sure of the command, you can add `-overwrite_original` to suppress the generation of backup files and `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.